# D3 V4 zoom to feature in canvas with stream projection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, geo

I'm trying to zoom to fit a `feature` in a streamed projection in canvas. I can already [select a feature](https://bl.ocks.org/Lacroute/579bc326fb547110a959c0a9ac2b30ce), but I can't achieve the zoom.

The method is simple, retrieve a feature, compute his centroid, and then apply a zoom transition to this point.

A very sumarized piece of code:

```
// variables
var land = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states)
var minZ // minimum area threshold for simplification

var transform = d3.geoIdentity().clipExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
var simplify = d3.geoTransform({
  point: function(x, y, z) { if (z >= minZ) this.stream.point(x, y)}
})

var path = d3.geoPath().projection({
  stream: function(s) { return simplify.stream(transform.stream(s)); }
})
.context(context);

// It's called backedProjection because the topojson is already projected with this
var backedProjection = d3.geoMercator().translate([0, 0]).scale(4000)


// zoom handler 
function zoomed(d) {
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  minZ = 1 / (t.k * t.k);
  transform.translate([t.x, t.y]).scale(t.k);
}


// click handler
function onClick() {
  let target = backedProjection(d3.geoCentroid(land));  

  let selectedTransform = d3.zoomIdentity
    .translate(width / 2, height / 2)
    .scale(0.05)
    .translate(-target[0], -target[1])

  // Apply the new transform
  canvas.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .call(
      zoom.transform,
      selectedTransform
  )
}
```

The stream projection system is a fork of @mbostock blocks https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7755778

Here is my block to test > 
http://blockbuilder.org/Lacroute/af1b46da4cb4579f93986b0119635ec2

Does anyone have an idea of why the zoom is broken?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved !

Zoom to centroid with dynamic simplification > https://bl.ocks.org/Fil/a8cfbbfd0100d38241beb48d23c9d4d1

Zoom to bounding box with dynamic simplification > https://bl.ocks.org/lacroute/af1b46da4cb4579f93986b0119635ec2